# cmd+delete and force touch not working in MS Word [MacOS]

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, magic-trackpad

In MacOS, you can delete line of text by cmd+delete. However, this command does not work in Microsoft Word. Is there any way to enable it?
Also, by force clicking the trackpad, you can look up the definition of a word. This too, does not work in MS Word.
I looked up but did not find any sources. I will be glad to know the answer/solution!

Comment: What version of Office are you using now? I test on Microsoft 365 (16.14), cmd+delete would delete text before cursor.

Comment: @Emily, MS Word (for Mac) version is 16.40. cmd+delete deletes one word but not the whole line of words.

Answer (score 1):

I know this comes a bit late, but for your second question there is a solution

Apparently it is possible to use third-parties softwares like [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) to reestablish a link between Force Touch and the Lookup function. All you need to do is set up Force Touch so that it activates the shortcut for Look up (in my MacBook, ctrl+cmd+D) in Microsoft Word. An example of how this looks like is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/beu9g9/reenabling_forcetouch_lookup_in_microsoft_word/).